# one subject has multiple observer

Tags: php, design-patterns

Which design pattern is used or how can it be done, so that one subject can have multiple observer and subject can notify specific observer when necessary. In classic observer pattern there is one function which is used to notify one observer or list of observer all at once, it cant notify specific observerver.

Comment: how do you identify *specific* observer? by reference? by id? how do you specify which one is that you want to be notified?

Comment: Observer will be another classes. I am thinking to store it in storage like one of kind object

Comment: @user2103335 maybe edit the question so it will be clear what's your expectation exactly for the bounty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Observer pattern* and its more generic variant *publish-subscribe idiom* are used to **decouple** observable from knowing its observers.

If the observable already knows the reference to the specific object that needs to be notified - just call that object directly.

You can also employ *publish-subscribe/event bus* - create a topic for each specific observer, make observers subscribe to specific topics and send event/publish to that topic.

Comment: can you tell difference between observer and eventbus design pattern?

Comment: event bus is an intermediary between observable and observers. observers register at eventbus rather than observable itself and observable notifies eventbus rather than observers directly. this way observable doesn't need to keep track of who's observing it and just delegates this to eventbus.

Comment: Sorry I did not get the answer. Can you please give me example?!

Answer (score 1):

Although i agree with what @mantrid said, you can still use the Observer pattern with filtering support or use the Pull model. For the first option add a method to your Observer interface like: `IsInterested(Object context)` where this method will be called by the Subject on all of its Observers to decide whether they should receive notifications and the subject may provide some information for the Observer through the `context` parameter to help it decide. For the second option, use a Pull model where your Subject notifies all Observers of some state change and those Observers has the choice to further request or don't request (pull information they want) new state information from the subject.

Comment: can you please give me example how to do so please?!